# Apply multiple policies in sails on a route

Tags: node.js, sails.js, policies

How to apply multiple policies in sails on routes which are generated by sails like this : `/users/:id/orders` . I can apply a single policy like this in config/routes.js

```
'/users/:id/orders' : {
   policy : 'isAuthenticated'
}
```

But how can apply more than one policy in similar manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the documentation http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?policy-target-syntax does not talk about chaining policies in routes.

As an alternative your could protect the populate action in your user controller like so: edit `config/policies.js`

```
UserController: {
    populate: ['isAuthenticated', 'isAllowed']
}
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where

If you just want to apply the policy only to the orders association, you can retrieve the association parameter (`/:model/:id/:association`) from the req object inside the policy and handle your case:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.param('association') == 'orders') {
      // do your magic
  } else {
     return next();
  }
};
```